# calling an external JS function from an external file

Tags: javascript, function

Okay so here is the situation.

I have a language toggle link embedded into a page, it changes the string of the URL from -eng.shtml to -fra.shtml along with the Alias value.

Now basically in the header i'm calling two scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/langDB.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/langToggle.js"></script>
```

LangToggle.js has a function within langDB.js but when the function programmed into langDB.js is called it doesn't quite work as expected, it's function should be to change the variable value from one to another.

Toggle code:

```
function js_changeit(){

    //Get the current page full URL 
        var mainName = String(window.location);

    //Base name
        var slash = mainName.lastIndexOf("/");  
        var dot = mainName.lastIndexOf(".");
        var quest = mainName.lastIndexOf("?");
        var name = mainName.substring(slash+1,dot);
        var ext = mainName.substring(dot,mainName.length);

    //Remove the _f is it exists
        var lang = name.substring(name.length-3,name.length);

    //Detect the site sections, get the current site title and the site primary alias strings
        var SiteSection = mainName.split("/");
        var currentAlias = SiteSection[3];
        var currentSite = SiteSection[2];

    //Split the url from Site to the end Alias section
        var siteSectionAlias = "http://" + currentSite + "/" + currentAlias + "/";
        var SectionaAlias = mainName.split(siteSectionAlias)
        var htmlFullDocFilename = SectionaAlias[1];

    //Extract the filename without the extension
        var shtmlLastPos = htmlFullDocFilename.lastIndexOf(".shtml");
        var docTitle = htmlFullDocFilename.substring(0,shtmlLastPos-4);     

    //Alias Toggles, when an alias is detected in the conditional list, switch to the other.


    langToggle();

    // Main Page
        if (lang != "eng") {
            window.open("http://" + currentSite + "/" + currentAlias + "/" + docTitle + "-eng" + ext, "_self");
        } else {
            window.open("http://" + currentSite + "/" + currentAlias + "/" + docTitle + "-fra" + ext, "_self");
        }
    }
```

function in langDB.js:

```
function langToggle() {
    switch(currentAlias) {
    //Switch the variable from English to French and vice versa depending on the current page's URL string when the toggle js link is clicked
        //If ENGLISH switch the variable to French
        case "about-us": 
            currentAlias = "a-notre-sujet"; break;
        //If FRENCH switch the variable to French
        case "a-notre-sujet": 
            currentAlias = "about-us"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "facilities-and-security": 
            currentAlias = "installations-et-securite"; break; 
        case "installations-et-securite": 
            currentAlias = "facilities-and-security"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "offenders": 
            currentAlias = "delinquants"; break; 
        case "delinquants": 
            currentAlias = "offenders"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "you-and-csc": 
            currentAlias = "scc-et-vous"; break; 
        case "scc-et-vous": 
            currentAlias = "you-and-csc"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "connecting": 
            currentAlias = "etablir-des-liens"; break; 
        case "etablir-des-liens": 
            currentAlias = "connecting"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "resources": 
            currentAlias = "ressources"; break; 
        case "ressources": 
            currentAlias = "resources"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "international-transfers": 
            currentAlias = "transferements-internationaux"; break; 
        case "transferements-internationaux": 
            currentAlias = "international-transfers"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "educational-resources": 
            currentAlias = "ressources-pedagogiques"; break; 
        case "ressources-pedagogiques": 
            currentAlias = "educational-resources"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "cfp": 
            currentAlias = "pfc"; break; 
        case "pfc": 
            currentAlias = "cfp"; break;
    }
}
```

when ever I'll click the language toggle link IE will give me an error that "currentAlias" is undefined, basically the value of the variable doesn't seem to load into the function called from an external script...

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: On which line does it give you the error?

Comment: Might I suggest some reading: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182416/A-Collection-of-JavaScript-Gotchas - see the section on Scope :)  You have a LOT of locally scoped variables in that function that seem to do little for you and might be better as an "object property"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when ever I'll click the language toggle link IE will give me an error that "currentAlias" is undefined...

That's because `currentAlias` is a *local variable* within the `js_changeit` function. `langToggle` can't access local variables within `js_changeit`.

<s>If your code really needs access to it, and these really have to be separate files, you'll have to have `js_changeit` put it in the global namespace (a property on `window`):</s>

```
window.currentAlias = currentAlias;
```

...and then use it from there. And you'll need to be sure that `js_changeit` runs before `langToggle` so the code putting it on `window` runs.

(I'm saying "global variable" and "property on `window`" interchangeably because all global variables are properties on the single [unnamed] JavaScript global object, and on browsers that object is accessible from the global variable `window` [`window` is a property pointing back to the object it's a property of].)

But if `langToggle` needs access to it, some refactoring may be appropriate, not least so you can avoid adding even more global symbols.

Sorry, just looked again at your code and saw that `js_changeit` *calls* `langToggle`. So the much, much better solution is for `js_changeit` to pass `currentAlias` into `langToggle` as an argument. No need for a global variable.

So change this line in `js_changeit`:

```
langToggle();
```

to:

```
currentAlias = langToggle(currentAlias);
```

And change `langToggle` so it accepts `currentAlias` as an argument and returns the updated value for it.

The bit where you're going astray is that a function doesn't inherit variables from the scope where it's *called*, it inherits them from the scope where it's *defined*. So `currentAlias` doesn't exist for `langToggle` because it's not declared in the scope where `langToggle` is declared.

Let's take a simpler example:

```
function foo() {
    var answer = 42;

    bar();
}

function bar() {
    console.log(answer); // <== Error, `answer` is not defined
}
```

`bar` is *called* from `foo`, but doesn't inherit `foo`'s variables. If `foo` wants to communicate something to `bar`, it would usually pass it in as an argument:

```
function foo() {
    var answer = 42;

    bar(answer);
}

function bar(a) {
    console.log(a); // This is fine
}
```

So then, if we call `foo`, `bar` will log "42".

Similarly if `bar` needs to communicate something back to `foo`, it will normally do that by returning a value:

```
function foo() {
    var answer = 42;
    var b;

    b = bar(answer);
    console.log(b);
}

function bar(a) {
    console.log(a);
    return a * 2;
}
```

Now if we call `foo`, `bar` will log "42" and `foo` will log "84".

There are other ways for `foo` and `bar` to share information (object properties, closures), but if you're new to this stuff that's plenty to be getting on with for now. :-)

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to coding.

Where exactly should I type window.currentAlias = currentAlias; ??

Comment: @user1795138: Actually, I just noticed something and updated the answer. No need for a global variable, see the update.

Comment: Okay so changed the code as you mentioned:

currentAlias = langToggle(currentAlias);

and in langToggle.js I changed function langToggle() {
to function langToggle(currentAlias) {

now if I hit the toggle it'll change the alias in the url tö "undefine" as in http://internet/undefined/index-fra.shtml instead of http://internet/a-notre-sujet/index-fra.shtml

Comment: @EricSP: Sounds like there's more going on. I've added some simplified examples of communication between functions above. Hopefully that will help you sort things out.

Comment: Sorry, I'm extremely lost...

So I shuld make js_changeit(currentAlias) and then...? Hmmm I really can't wrap my head around this. Will need to review it a few times.

Comment: @EricSP: *"So I shuld make js_changeit(currentAlias)"* No, because `currentAlias` is a local variable **within** `js_changeit`.

Comment: Well I'll be doing more reading on this subject but in the end I found a much simpler solution. I changed var currentAlias to simply "currentAlias" so that it becomes a global variable and now the toggle works perfectly fine.

I'm going to see how to transfer a local variable from one function to another and return its value later on... thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: Hey guys, I've got it!

var UpdatedAlias = langToggle(currentAlias);
langToggle();

and in my langToggle() I coded it this way:

unction langToggle(currentAlias) {
 switch(currentAlias) {
 //Switch the variable from English to French and vice versa depending on the current page's URL string when the toggle js link is clicked
  //If ENGLISH switch the variable to French
  case "about-us": 
   currentAlias = "a-notre-sujet";
   return currentAlias;
   break;
  //If FRENCH switch the variable to French
  case "a-notre-sujet": 
   currentAlias = "about-us";
   return currentAlias;
   break;

Answer (score 0):

Well,  you should take the error message exactly as it is.  If you look at your langToggle function, you immediately try to reference currentAlias, but it has not been defined yet in the function's scope.

I see you have defined it in the scope of function js_changeit, but the declaration would only be available in the scope of that function not in the langToggle function scope.